# Mocha TDD, Chai-http not logging any response

Tags: tdd, mocha.js, chai-http

I am trying to test an authentication api using chai-http, however I am not able to get any response for this particular block -

```
describe('Authenticate user', () => {
it('Should Authenticate user', () => {
    let server = require(process.cwd() + "/server.js")
    let token
    chai.request(server)
        .post('/api/authenticate')
        .send({
            "userid": "Jeetendra",
            "password": "abcd1234"
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log('Inside authenticate result block')
            console.log(res)
            token = res.body.data
        },err => {
           console.log('Inside authenticate error block')
            // token = res.body.data
            console.log(err)
        })
  })
})
```

For the above code block I am not getting any of the logs printed. Can anyone please help what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your code is running asynchronously. You need to pass the `done` callback to your test case, then call it in order to flag test completion

```
it('Should Authenticate user', (done) => {
    let server = require(process.cwd() + "/server.js")
    let token
    chai.request(server)
        .post('/api/authenticate')
        .send({
            "userid": "Jeetendra",
            "password": "abcd1234"
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log('Inside authenticate result block')
            console.log(res)
            token = res.body.data
            done()
        },err => {
           console.log('Inside authenticate error block')
            // token = res.body.data
            console.log(err)
            done(err)
        })
  })
```

Comment: This is still giving me problems the promise never gets resolved.

Comment: wrap the entire thing in a `try-catch` block....if you are caught in urllib2 issues, you may not have a promise return,reject, or raise.

Answer (score 2):

## Mocha Gotcha

Taken from [Mocha docs](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions):

> Passing arrow functions (“lambdas”) to Mocha is discouraged. Due to the lexical binding of this, such functions are unable to access the Mocha context.

Using `done()` kind of kills the purpose of Promise all together. Usually just changing `=>` into a `function(){}` in `it` fixes the problem.

```
describe('Authenticate user', () => {
  it('Should Authenticate user', function(){ // use function rather than arrow
   let server = require(process.cwd() + "/server.js")
   let token
   chai.request(server)
     .post('/api/authenticate')
     .send({
       "userid": "Jeetendra",
       "password": "abcd1234"
     })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('Inside authenticate result block')
      console.log(res)
      token = res.body.data
    },err => {
      console.log('Inside authenticate error block')
      // token = res.body.data
      console.log(err)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will surely keep that in mind.